# api call is getting failed after 4 minutes of waiting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I am making an API call from client side but it is getting failed after 4 mins of waiting.

But when I run the same query in Oracle SQL Developer it is taking the same time but is showing the data there.

I am using the **ReactJS** for the frontend and **nodeJS** for the backend.

So can anyone tell me what should I change in frontend so that API call should not get failed and can render the data.

In **Postman** also, it is throwing the error - *could not get response after waiting a long time*.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    // debugger;
    // event.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/country`)
    .then(response => {
      // console.log(response);
      const country_Claim_Type = response.data;
      this.setState({ country_Claim_Type 

      });
        console.log('data fetched');
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/countryDollar`)
    }).then(response => {
      // console.log(response);
      const country_Claim_Dollar = response.data;
      this.setState({ country_Claim_Dollar 

      });
        console.log('data fetched');
```

```
            return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/claimQuarter`)
        }).then(res => {
              const claims = res.data;
              let claim = [];
              let puru = [];
              claims.forEach(element => {
                claim.push(element.COUNT);  
                puru.push(element.USD);
              });
              this.setState({ 
                Data: {
                  labels: ['FY19 Q1[NOV-JAN]','FY19 Q2[FEB-APR]','FY18[SEP-NOV]'],
                  datasets:[
                     {
                        label:'',
                        data: claim ,puru,
                        backgroundColor:[
                         'rgba(255,105,145,0.6)',
                         'rgba(155,100,210,0.6)',
                         'rgb(63, 191, 191)'

                      ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
               });
```

```
           return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/claimType`)
        }) .then(barGraph => { 
          const claims = barGraph.data;
           let claimcount = [];
          let claimtype = [];
          claims.forEach(element => {
             claimcount.push(element.COUNT);
            claimtype.push(element.CLT_NAME);
          });
          this.setState({ 
            Claim_Type: {
               labels: claimtype,
              datasets:[
                 {
                    label:'',
                    data: claimcount ,
                    backgroundColor:[

                     'rgba(255,105,145,0.6)',
                     'rgba(155,100,210,0.6)',
                     'rgb(255, 0, 64)',
                     'rgb(191, 255, 0)',
                     'rgb(0, 255, 255)',
                     'rgb(128, 0, 255)'
                  ]
                 }
              ]
           }
           });
           return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/claimCountry`)
        }).then(countryList => {
          const claims = countryList.data;
          let claimcount = [];
          let country = [];
          var coloR = [];
          const percent = "%";
          // let claimvalue = [];
          let claimTotal = 0;
          var dynamicColors = function() {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
         };
          claims.forEach(element => {
           claimTotal+=element.COUNT;
         });
          claims.forEach(element => {
            claimcount.push(parseFloat((element.COUNT/claimTotal)*100).toFixed(2));
            //  claimvalue.push(element.USD);
            country.push(element.COUNTRY);
            coloR.push(dynamicColors());
          });
          this.setState({ 
            country_claim: {
               labels: country,
               datasets:[
                 {
                    label:'ClaimCounts',
                    data: claimcount, 
                    backgroundColor: coloR
                 }
              ]
           }
           });
           return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/claimDollar`)
          }).then(res => {
            const claims = res.data;
            let dollar = [];
            claims.forEach(element => {
              dollar.push(element.USD);
            });
            this.setState({ 
              dollar_value: {
                labels: ['Q1','Q2','FY18'],
                datasets:[
                   {
                      label:'',
                      data: dollar ,
                      backgroundColor:[
                       'rgba(255,105,145,0.6)',
                       'rgba(155,100,210,0.6)',
                       'rgb(63, 191, 191)'

                    ]
                   }
                ]
             }
             });
            })

  }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code and error messages. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the error message and where is it coming from?

Comment: The error is GET http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/claimQuarter net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

If your database connection is right, and It's just take a long time to get data then cause timeout error. You only need to increase you request timeout, in express is like this:

```
req.setTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Ok but can you tell me where to put that code in claimQuarter API section that I have highlighted ? its the middle one code

Comment: First increase your axios timeout.
`axios({ url: '...', timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000 })`
Then, increase your backend request timeout, It's depend on your backend framework.

Comment: API call is not responding because it is taking so much time. I tried your method and is not working. It is not able to load the data in the browser.

Comment: Except I said, still have some configs, mybe webpack proxy timeout, nginx timeout. I think you need to find out why your api call take so long time. The long time api call may cause network block. By default chrome only allow max six connections per domain in HTTP/1.1.